# Error System.IO.FileNotFoundException al intentar cargar Archivo Excel

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy utilizando un FileDialog para seleccionar un archivo Excel o CSC mostralo en un dgv y posterior a esto subirlo a la base de datos, pero estoy recibiendo el siguiente error:
**System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not find file 'C:\Users\jdani\OneDrive\Documentos\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\SoftwareRobot\SoftwareRobot\bin\Debug\FileDialog'.'**

He estado buscando posibles soluciones y mencionan en muchas de ellas poner en false la referencia del System.IO, pero esta esta ya en false entonces que mas me recomiendan hacer para solucionar el problema?

Este es el código que tengo hasta el momento:

```
private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        fileDialog.Multiselect = false;
        fileDialog.Title = "Import file";
        fileDialog.Filter = "Excel Workbook|*.xlsx| CSV File|* .csv";
        fileDialog.DefaultExt = ".xlsx";

        if (fileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string fileName;
            fileName = fileDialog.FileName;
            txtPath.Text = fileName;

            using (var stream = File.Open(openFileDialog.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {

                {
                    using (IExcelDataReader reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
                    {
                        DataSet result = reader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration()
                        {
                            ConfigureDataTable = (_) => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration()
                            { UseHeaderRow = true }
                        });
                        tableCollection = result.Tables;
                        cboSheet.Items.Clear();
                        foreach (DataTable table in tableCollection)
                            cboSheet.Items.Add(table.TableName);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void cboSheet_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = tableCollection[cboSheet.SelectedItem.ToString()];
        DGVFile.DataSource = dt;
    }
```

Agradezco de antemano cualquier ayuda.

Saludos

DS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Su error se produce porque abre el archivo con

```
using (var stream = File.Open(openFileDialog.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
```

utilizando la instancia openFileDialog, pero el cuadro de dialogo que instancia en el metodo esta referenciado por fileDialog. Debe abrirlo así

```
using (var stream = File.Open(fileDialog.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
```

Comment: Gracias, tienes razón, saludos
@Mauricio Ortega